# input pipeline in tensorflow

Tags: python, input, tensorflow, jpeg

While practicing on the official tensorflow mnist dataset tutorial for beginners, I'm trying to change the mnist data to my own images collected from search engines.

```
strFilePaths,iLabels ,strSubFolderNames,iNumTotalDatasets = ScanForImage('Datasets')

tsFileNameQueue = tf.train.string_input_producer(strFilePaths)
tsReader = tf.WholeFileReader()
_,tsImage = tsReader.read(tsFileNameQueue)

tsImage = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tsImage, channels=3)
tsImage = tf.cast(tsImage,tf.float32)
tsLabels = tf.convert_to_tensor(iLabels, dtype=tf.float32)
tsImage = tf.reshape(tsImage, shape=[1,168*300*3])

matWeights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([168*300*3, 2]))
vBiases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))
vPredictions = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(tsImage, matWeights) + vBiases)
fCrossEntropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(tsLabels * tf.log(vPredictions), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(fCrossEntropy)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess : 
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range (1000) : 
    tsTrainingSets = tf.train.batch([tsImage,tsLabels], batch_size=100)
    sess.run(train_step)
        if i % 20 == 0 : 
            correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(vPredictions,1),tf.argmax(tsTrainingSets[1],1))
            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,tf.float32))
            print(sess.run(accuracy))
```

That strFilePaths is a standard python list containing all my image paths , iLabels is a list of lists representing labels. And I have only 2 classes in this case.

This program runs without error output but tensorflow just keeps on running and not giving me any output. I've read the "reading files" session in tensorflow website for like a thousand times but I still don't have a clue on whether I did things right or not.

Q1: What's wrong with this code?
Q2: Is there any complete example on how to read jpeg files into tensorflow and perform some training tasks on them?

Comment: Image Retraining tutorial uses decode jpeg, ie https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4433079e7f317724eaa92ec120c6b1c3c0c52f2f/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, without access to your code and files, I am unable to help you debug further. However, you can see a full example of how to retrain Inception to recognize new categories of information (e.g. flowers) in the `image_retraining` example at: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py